# Light scattering and absorption of an infinite collimated beam

Tags: visible-light, scattering, differential-equations

Consider the following problem:

[image]

Here a semi-infinite material with scattering coefficient $\mu_s$ and absorption coefficient $\mu_\alpha$ is illuminated with an infinite collimated beam of initial intensity $E_0$.

At any point along $z$ a photon can stray from it's path towards a new direction with a probability given by the phase function $p(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the original and the new direction. Suppose that **only a single scattering event takes place for every photon**.

Then at each point in the medium light intensity towards an angle $\theta$ (I use angle and direction interchangeably) is generated by a source term $\varepsilon(z,\theta)$ of the form that is shown in the picture.

Now I need to find the total scattered intensity towards direction $\theta$  at a point $r_1$ inside the medium. Parametrizing the distance between $r_1$ and a point on the boundary at $(x_1 - \Delta x, z_1 - \Delta z_2)$, we can get a distance $s$ that takes values from $0$ to $\sqrt{(\left(\Delta x\right)^2 + \left(\Delta z_2\right)^2)}$.

Then the differential equation of light intensity or irradiance along $s$ will be of the form:
$$
\frac{dI}{ds}=-(\mu_\alpha + \mu_s)\cdotΙ + \text{source term}
$$

My question is:

Shoud the source term be equal to $\varepsilon(z,\theta)$ or should it involve the integral of $\varepsilon(z,\theta)$ for all $s$?

Also, in the second case it has to be considered that light generated at any point along $s$ will be attenuated with a factor of $\exp\left(-(\mu_\alpha + \mu_s)\Delta s\right)$ before it reaches $r_1$. Should this factor be present in the differential equation or is it taken into account by $-(\mu_\alpha + \mu_s)\cdot Ι$?